# Why new Route in Laravel v6.9.0 is not working? Vindows 10 - XAMPP v3.2.4 (64bit)

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, routes

I'm first time working in Laravel.

I've installed composer.

Installed Laravel v6.9.0 in Windows 10 with XAMPP v3.2.4 (64bit), and
PHP v7.3.12.0

im cute files from public folder in root and public folder delete

My **test .htaccess** by 
[htaccess_tester](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bolt/htaccess_tester/master/htaccess_tester.php) had **worked**

The test for **mod_rewrite** shows it is enabled and **working**
**httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

In my check to Apache **httpd.conf** with all **AllowOverride None** changed to **AllowOverride All**

and appended end file **httpd.conf** file:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/Laravel Project/moda.local">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
Allow from All</Directory>
```

my **.htaccess** code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]</IfModule>
```

My **routes.php** in code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {return view('welcome');});
Route::get('/test1', function () {return 'test1';});
Route::get('test2', function () {return 'test2';});
```

my VirtualHost in c:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName moda.local
 DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/Laravel Project/moda.local"
 SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
 <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/Laravel Project/moda.local">
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
 </Directory></VirtualHost>
```

**My URL:**

-this url **worked** no problem show laravel first page
http://moda.local/

-this url **not work** error > 404 not found
http://moda.local/test1

-this url **not work** error > 404 not found
http://moda.local/test2

Comment: what was the error? see in `app/storage/log` folder

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Please add error details also good to know: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: where you use `chdir` in your code?

Comment: What is `moda.local`?

Comment: moda.local is my VirtualHost

Comment: Why aren't you pointing to the public directory of your application? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x#web-server-configuration

Comment: no i dont use chdir this log file error for 12 Desember but no 24 Desember this is old error

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x#web-server-configuration not help no me not worked